# Record and play audio - python

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm going to implement a voice chat using python. So I saw few examples, how to play sound and how to record. In many examples they used `pyAudio` library.
I'm able to record voice and able to save it in `.wav` file. And I'm able play a `.wav` file. But I'm looking for record voice for 5 seconds and then play it. I don't want to save it into file and then playing, it's not good for voice chat.

Here is my audio record code:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=RATE,
        input=True, output=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE)
num_silent = 0
snd_started = False

r = array('h')

while 1:
    # little endian, signed short
    snd_data = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
    if byteorder == 'big':
        snd_data.byteswap()
    r.extend(snd_data)

    silent = is_silent(snd_data)

    if silent and snd_started:
        num_silent += 1
    elif not silent and not snd_started:
        snd_started = True

    if snd_started and num_silent > 30:
        break
```

Now I want to play it without saving. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not like this library try '`sounddevice`' and '`soundfile`'its are very easy to use and to implement.
for record and play voice use this:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf 


sr = 44100
duration = 5
myrecording = sd.rec(int(duration * sr), samplerate=sr, channels=2)
sd.wait()  
sd.play(myrecording, sr)
sf.write("New Record.wav", myrecording, sr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Having looked through the [PyAudio Documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/), you've got it all as it should be but what you're forgetting is that `stream` is a **duplex** descriptor.  This means that you can read from it to record sound (as you have done with `stream.read`) and you write to it to play sound (with `stream.write`).

Thus the last few lines of your example code should be:

```
# Play back collected sound.
stream.write(r)

# Cleanup the stream and stop PyAudio
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```